# Python re.sub appends string instead of replacing it

Tags: python, regex

I am new to Python and am stuck on a regular expression replacement. I am parsing a settings file which has statements such as:

```
set fmri(convolve7) 3
```

The settings file is used as a template. The script parses through the template and writes a new settings file with updated settings.

The  main structure of my program is

```
for line in infile:
 if condition = true
  for each in listofelements
    if re.search(each, line):
     print(re.sub(r"\d+", "0", line), file=outfile, end='') # double output
 if re.search(somethingelse, line):
  print(re.sub(templatesubid, i, line), file=outfile, end='')# normal substitution
```

etc.

The substitution in the for loop results in double output, wheras outside the for loop it does't. The for loop seems to inserts a newline with the correct substitution string, i.e.

```
set fmri(convolve7) 0
set fmri(convolve7) 3
```

The other substitions work as expected, wheras it is the same code. Can it be that the for loop causes this double output?

Comment: Could you trim that code down into a more succinct example?

Comment: this is too long ... you will not get an answer ... but re.sub indeed replaces matches ... `print re.sub("p+","b","Apple")`

Comment: As this is python, `if condition:` would be sufficient, and `if condition = true` will always be true (assignment as opposed to comparison), and I think should be a syntax error due to the missing colon.  In either case, you're hitting both that print statement, and the second print statment.  You probably want one or the other.

Comment: the first if condition in my example is indeed in crippled phonetic python, and you are right about that it would break. More importantly, the first if statement catches an exception. I think I will need to restructure and place the first if statement one level up. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the relevant code is at the bottom:

```
    for line in infile:
        if len(subparamlist) > 0:
            for j in subparamlist:
                query = j.replace(")", "\)").replace("(", "\(")
                if re.search(query, line):
                    print(re.sub(r"\d+", "0", line), file=outfile, end='') #trouble!
        if re.search(templatesubid, line) and re.search('feat_files\(', line) or re.search('\(custom', line) : # correct the subjectID
            print(re.sub(templatesubid, i, line), file=outfile, end='')
        elif re.search(str(nptslist[2]), line): # correct the number of timepoints
            print(re.sub(str(nptslist[2]), str(nvols[0]), line), file = outfile, end='')
        else: 
            print(line, file=outfile, end='') # if nothing to do, just copy the line to the new text file.
```

I think the problem is that you're printing in both the top `if` statement (substituting `0` into the line), and then printing again in one of the branches of the `if/elif/else` block below it. This result is some (or all) lines being doubled.

I didn't actually understand the code well enough to work out an appropriate fix, but a possible start might be to change the `if` you've commented with "correct the subjectID" to an `elif`.

Comment: I changed the line to elif, but then I only get: set fmri(convolve0) 0
set fmri(convolve0) 0 as an output. Your suggestions helps me thinking - so thanks for the very quick responses!